# Cant get Global errorhandler to work on my selfhosting wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, global, ierrorhandler

Hello i've tried to get the Ierrorhandler to work now for hours and im pretty stuck :)
i've gotten the most results out of this guide

http://www.remondo.net/wcf-global-exception-handling-attribute-and-ierrorhandler/#comment-10385

but i cant get it to work with my opertations/functions

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Phpwcfconsole
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1)))
            {
                try
                {
                    host.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Host open. Press any key to <EXIT>");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    host.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
                    host.Close(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="Phpwcfconsole.Service1Behavior" 
        name="Phpwcfconsole.Service1">
    <endpoint 
      address="" 
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      contract="Phpwcfconsole.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://agent007:8732/phpwcf/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="Phpwcfconsole.Service1Behavior">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
         </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="MyServiceBinding"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                maxBufferSize="20000000"
                maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
                transferMode="Buffered"
                messageEncoding="Text"
                textEncoding="utf-8"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
           <security mode="None" />
         </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
   </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

**IService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;


namespace Phpwcfconsole
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
}
```

**Serverfunctions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Phpwcfconsole
{
    public partial class Service1 : IService
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            throw new Exception("error");
        }
    }
}
```

**ExeceptionHandler.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

namespace Phpwcfconsole
{
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception ex)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception ex, MessageVersion version,
                             ref Message msg)
        {
            // Do some logging here

            var newEx = new FaultException(
                string.Format("CALLED FROM YOUR GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLER BY {0}",
                              ex.TargetSite.Name));

            MessageFault msgFault = newEx.CreateMessageFault();
            msg = Message.CreateMessage(version, msgFault, newEx.Action);
        }
    }

    public class GlobalExceptionHandlerBehaviourAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
    {
        private readonly Type _errorHandlerType;

        public GlobalExceptionHandlerBehaviourAttribute(Type errorHandlerType)
        {
            _errorHandlerType = errorHandlerType;
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase     serviceHostBase)
        {

        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
            Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            var handler = (IErrorHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(_errorHandlerType);

            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase dispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                var channelDispatcher = dispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (channelDispatcher != null)
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ok so if i put some console.writeLine inside

**public class GlobalExceptionHandlerBehaviourAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior**
functions i see that they run when i start the program. but i cant get the example on the guide working with my function to throw a exception and get that one caught by my IErrorhandler.

i've tried some exceptions inside other functions and nothing happens with my IErrorhandler.

But one exception get caught in it that i discovered so far its when i add my service in **Wcftestclient** and then stop debug and remove **[OperationContract]** in my **IService.cs** and then start again and try to run the function without refreshing, that exception get caught by the IErrorhandler

so my problem here is why cant i catch exceptions inside a function?
thank you so much for answers.
c(:

Comment: hmm watching this site [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx very carefully i  saw down at the requirements that i have windows xp with .net 4.0 installed. running windows update now with thumbs crossed.

Comment: anyone know anything about this? which platforms do you use for wcf services?

Answer (score 0):

Would the FaultContractAttribute be sufficient for what you are trying to do?
Take a look at the example in the msdn doc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx
It sounds similar to what you are trying to do, with less complexity than a custom service behavior.

FaultContracts are the equivalent of exceptions when using WCF across processes/machines since consumers aren't necessarily .net clients.